# jquery ajax returning query string in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am working on a simple ajax mail, my html looks like this:

```
<form id="contact_form">
        <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="[ NAME ]" type="text"> <br />
        <input name="company" id="company" placeholder="[ COMPANY ]" type="text"> <br />
        <input name="designation" id="designation" placeholder="[ DESIGNATION ]" type="text"> <br />
        <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="[ PHONE ]" type="text"> <br />
        <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="[ EMAIL ]" type="text"> <br />
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="50" style="color:#FFF;" Placeholder="[ HOW CAN WE HELP? ]"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" style="width:262px; height:30px;"> 
        <div id="result" style="background-color:#7A706B; color:#FFF; text-align:center; width:280px; height:250px; position:absolute; left:10px; top:30px; padding-top:100px; display:none; font-size:16px;"> You Expressed. We Understand.<br /><br />[Welcome to the world of business innovation]<br /><br />You’ll be clarified shortly…</div>
        </form>
```

and my jquery looks like this:

```
$(function() {
$("#submit_btn").click(function(){
var data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    company: $("#company").val(),
    designation: $("#designation").val(),
    phone: $("#phone").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    message: $("#message").val()
};
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mail.php",
data: data,
cache: false,
success: function(result){ 
  $( "#result" ).fadeIn(1000);
}
});
});
});
```

the problem is when i click on submit button, it shows all data in address bar instead of sending it to mail.php via POST method.

PS: when i use alert() instead of $( "#result" ).fadeIn(1000); it works fine.

anyone can help please?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cancel the submission and use the submit event instead of the click

```
$(function() {
  $("#contact_form").on("submit",function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // will cancel the submit even if errors below

    // rest of code

  });
});
```

Note to commenters:

The valid use case for a submit button is that pressing enter will trigger the submit handler. That is often useful. If you do NOT want enter to submit, then indeed make the button type=button and assign the ajax handler to the click of this button instead of submit.

Comment: The form has no action the submit button only calls the ajax script I don't think this is necessary?

Comment: Yes it is very necessary. Default action is to send the data to same page your are on. Which is exactly what is happening

Comment: Yes it returns whatever data from PHP into result. How does using preventDefault() prevent his ajax from not sending data. Think its more of an absolute URL issue.

Comment: No. His ajax is interrupted by the actual submission of the form since the submit event is not cancelled

Comment: hi Edward, exactly what my problem was, i took of un used form tags and it works perfectly now. fyi: www.quantumfactual.com is the link.

thanks for the tip

Comment: In this case I'm a little confused why are you using ajax to send the form data when you are submitting the form to PHP via the submit button ?

Comment: To not reload the page. One of the big reasons for using Ajax at all

Comment: Then wouldn't he just change the input type ="submit" to "text" from his submit button and he doesnt have to use preventDefault();

Comment: Not necessary. The submit button makes sense. Please look at some Ajax tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Add e.preventDefault(); to your click callback:

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try entering an absolute URL instead of `url: "mail.php"`. and also `return false;` at the end of your `click(function(){});` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Three points

- **you have to prevent the default action via `event.preventDefault()`**
- listen for the submit event rather than the click event
- use `.serialize()` method to gather the data

First point is necessary for your code to work; the other two are recommendations.

```
$(function() {
    $("#contact_form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){ 
                $( "#result" ).fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**BONUS**

Just so that you may understand the difference between `GET` (default) and `POST` if you make just the following change in your HTML, you will not see the data in the address bar. Yet your form will still not be submitted via ajax as the the default action is still in effect.

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post">
```